# Access values of object from within a javascript closure

Tags: javascript, object, closures

I can't get how to access that value, this is my code:

```
function Filters()
{
    this.filters = ["filter_1", "filter_2", "filter_3"];
    this.someData = "test";
    this.draw = draw;
    function draw(){
        for(var i=0; i<this.filters.length;i++)
        {
            var filter = this.filters[i];
            $("#" + filter).click(function(){
                doSomething();
            });
        }
    }
    function doSomething(){
        alert(this.someData);
    }
}
```

I am aware of the fact that since `doSomething()` is called from within the closure, `this.` will refer a JQuery object being worked on. So how do I go about being able to use `someData` from my object in that function/closure ? Can't seem to figure it out.
Thanks for help :)

Comment: No. It would be the jQuery object if you did `.click(doSomething)`. Currently it's nothing (or the global object).

Comment: Daniel, `Filters()` is a constructor, written to be called with `new Filters()`. As written the constructor will behave very differently if called without `new`. To understand the issues here, and to learn how to write constructors that are tolerant of a missing `new`, try [this, by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/). It's fairly heavyweight stuff but worth persisting with.

Comment: You probably also need to read Douglas Crockford's [Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot : yeah I know it is a constructor, I intended to write a class, with parameters passed to the constructor etc. I have cut all that out and left only what I considered relevant. I will have a read through the articles you have linked, thanks :)

Comment: Daniel, sorry I didn't mean to lecture you on what you already know. Between them, those two articles will teach you lots about javascript. I wish they had been available 15 years earlier when I started the JS strand of my career.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `this` inside `doSomething` will be the global object. You need to keep a reference to `this` in a separate variable:

```
function Filters()
{
    var that = this; // reference to this
    this.filters = ["filter_1", "filter_2", "filter_3"];
    this.someData = "test";
    this.draw = draw;
    function draw(){
        for(var i=0; i<this.filters.length;i++)
        {
            var filter = this.filters[i];
            $("#" + filter).click(function(){
                doSomething();
            });
        }
    }
    function doSomething(){
        alert(that.someData);
    }
}
```

Unrelated to your problem: you could also pass a reference to `doSomething` as the event listener, instead of wrapping it in another function:

```
$("#" + filter).click(doSomething);
```